# Global Network Auto-Login bug on Ubuntu-Firefox

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, auto-login

I'm using Firefox 3.6.18 and Ubuntu 10.04. [Network Login Troubleshoot](https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help) says I'm OK.

I've logged out of Cooking.SE. I've turned off my computer (had to go). I went to meta.SO. I went to Cooking.SE...

[image: Q&A Notification]

Then I went to 'log in' to force login and no cigar.
[image: Login screen]

I'll have to type my SE.OpenID to login.

Comment: OK, status-bydesign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've logged out of Cooking.SE.

This clears your SE network cookie (but not any other existing logins), as displayed on the logout page. To reinstate this cookie, you need to relogin to a SE site.

Comment: I did that: "I went to meta.SE".

Comment: Going to MSO doesn't count, you actually have to go through the entire login procedure on one site to reinstate the cookie.

Comment: Meta.SO (typo). OK, I got that. Still, weird that pushing 'login' doesn't force login.